# data.table: calculation condition on presence of value within group

Tags: r, data.table

With some data

```
library(data.table); set.seed(42)
dat <- data.table(id=1:5, group=c(1,1,1,2,2), time=c(1,2,3,1,2), val=runif(5))
> dat
   id group time       val
1:  1     1    1 0.9148060
2:  2     1    2 0.9370754
3:  3     1    3 0.2861395
4:  4     2    1 0.8304476
5:  5     2    2 0.6417455
```

and I would like to apply some calculation, say `val*2`, to time point 2 only to those groups for which there is no third time point. The expected output is therefore

```
> res
   id group time       val
1:  1     1    1 0.9148060
2:  2     1    2 0.9370754
3:  3     1    3 0.2861395
4:  4     2    1 0.8304476
5:  5     2    2 1.2834910
```

where the value of time 2 in group 2 was changed. 
I suspected it is something along the lines of

```
dat[,val:=val[max(time)==2]*2, by=group]
```

but this would not work. Because I want to apply the calculation to a different time point than the one I am subsetting on, I felt this can't be done in `i` but I would not know how to do it instead.

Comment: Could you just add a column with your expected outcome please? I'm not sure I get it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my previous answer (before edit) and on @Axeman's one, you could do the following

```
dat[, val2 := if(max(time) == 2) ifelse(time==2, 2*val, val) else val, group][]
##     id group time       val      val2
##  1:  1     1    1 0.9148060 0.9148060
##  2:  2     1    2 0.9370754 0.9370754
##  3:  3     1    3 0.2861395 0.2861395
##  4:  4     2    1 0.8304476 0.8304476
##  5:  5     2    2 0.6417455 1.2834910
```

and replace the `2*val` by any function you would like.

Comment: Perhaps they want `dat[, .(id, time, val, val2 = if(max(time) == 2) 2 * val else val), group]`?

Comment: Hoo, maybe! I'll just wait @bumblebee to edit his/her question, I'll edit my answer afterwards

Comment: Thanks to both of you! @Axeman is closer to what I am looking for (desired output added) and irrespective of the solution I have learned already that `if(.)` can be used inside data.table.

Comment: @J.P.LeCavalier The solution in the other answer above gets the correct result but is very specific to the `val*2` calculation. Is your solution modifiable to produce a more general solution?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```r
dat[, val := val*(1 + (time==2 & max(time)==2)), by=group]
##    id group time       val
## 1:  1     1    1 0.9148060
## 2:  2     1    2 0.9370754
## 3:  3     1    3 0.2861395
## 4:  4     2    1 0.8304476
## 5:  5     2    2 1.2834910
```

Comment: elegant, thanks! However, the `val*2`was merely an example. I would need a more general solution.

Answer (score 0):

The data is sorted by time, so we can join on the last row per group and edit iff it meets the criterion:

```
dat[.(unique(group)), on=.(group), mult="last", 
  val := if (time == 2) val*2 else val
, by=.EACHI]
```

We can use `if`/`else` because `mult="last"` (and `nomatch=NA`) guarantees that `time` has a length of 1. (This contrasts with the other two answers where the full time vector for each group is handled.)